# Periodic Snapshot of Geomesa Table to restore data images

Tags: geomesa

Does Geomesa provide ability to create HBase table snapshots? If yes, then how it works with primary and index table? To ensure index table and primary table are in sync, What it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GeoMesa does not provide any mechanism to take snapshots in HBase, however, the standard HBase snapshot mechanisms work fine. As long as you're not performing any administrative operations on GeoMesa while taking the snapshots there won't be any issues around keeping the GeoMesa metadata table and the index tables in sync.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to ensure that index tables have the same, consistent features among themselves, you should pause ingest before taking a snapshot.